# Samsung SSD 840/850 EVO with DiskCryptor?

Tags: encryption, hardware, ssd

Samsung's [840/850 EVO SSDs](http://www.samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/minisite/SSD/global/html/ssd850evo/overview.html) have hardware full disk encryption feature, however the stock disk management app (Magician) only mentions BitLocker's support.

> Encrypted Drive feature provided by BitLocker® Drive Encryption in Windows® 8 and Windows Server® 2012.

As user of Windows 10 Home I am not able to use this feature (BitLocker is available only in Pro / Ultimate versions of Windows). While looking for an alternative I came across DiskCryptor (TrueCrypt doesn't seem too reliable now). [The website](https://diskcryptor.net/wiki/Main_Page) mentions support for hardware AES acceleration, but only on CPU side(?):

> Support for hardware AES acceleration:
>      AES New Instructions set on recent Intel and AMD CPUs;
>      PadLock extensions on VIA processors.

Will DiskCryptor benefit from EVO's hardware encryption feature? If not, are there another BitLocker and TrueCrypt alternatives that would make use of it?

I am only interested in FDE using disk hardware solutions. Engaging CPU power in my case isn't worth it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DiskCryptor will likely not benefit from the hardware FDE stuff on the SSD. The best information I can find is that the drive always encrypts, it's just a question of whether or not the key is password protected, as it should be to actually be relevant.

If your BIOS/EFI supports it, you can actually enable it there:
Security > Password on boot > HDD Password (Will differ depending on the BIOS)
This should then "just work".

EDIT: There's some really interesting discussion here: http://www.sevenforums.com/hardware-devices/314650-my-review-samsung-840-evo-ssd-full-drive-encryption.html